# SWIFT delete UIButton when button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Using SWiFT SpriteKit I want to delete both 'createLeftButtonFirst' and 'createLeftButtonFirst' buttons from the screen when 'buttonPressedLeftFirst' and 'buttonPressedRightFirst' is pressed. Any chance you could help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
func createLeftButton () {
    let button = UIButton();
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width - self.frame.width, 0, self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height) // X, Y, width, height
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressedRight:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view!.addSubview(button)
    button.layer.zPosition = 0

}

func createRightButton () {

    let buttonRight = UIButton();

    buttonRight.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width / 2, 0, self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height) // X, Y, width, height
    buttonRight.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    buttonRight.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressedLeft:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view!.addSubview(buttonRight)
    buttonRight.layer.zPosition = 0

}

func createLeftButtonFirst () {
    let buttonFirst = UIButton();
    buttonFirst.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width - self.frame.width, 0, self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height) // X, Y, width, height
    buttonFirst.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    buttonFirst.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressedRightFirst:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view!.addSubview(buttonFirst)
    buttonFirst.layer.zPosition = 1

}

func createRightButtonFirst () {

    let buttonRightFirst = UIButton();

    buttonRightFirst.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width / 2, 0, self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height) // X, Y, width, height
    buttonRightFirst.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    buttonRightFirst.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressedLeftFirst:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view!.addSubview(buttonRightFirst)
    buttonRightFirst.layer.zPosition = 1

}


func buttonPressedRight(sender: UIButton!) {


    if buttonPressed == 0 {

    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -15, dy: 0))
        buttonPressed = 1


    }

}
func buttonPressedLeft(sender: UIButton!) {
    if buttonPressed == 1 {

    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 15, dy: 0))
        buttonPressed = 0

    }
}


/* First Buttons*/
func buttonPressedRightFirst(sender: UIButton!){

    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -15, dy: 0))
    buttonPressed = 1




}

func buttonPressedLeftFirst(sender: UIButton!){

    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 15, dy: 0))
    buttonPressed = 0
    self.removeFromParent()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality can be achieved by making them `hidden` when they're pressed:

```
func leftButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    leftButton.hidden = true
    rightButton.hidden = true
}

func rightButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    leftButton.hidden = true
    rightButton.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: By the way, I think the buttons should be defined outside the functions that "create" them. Just do `weak var leftButton: UIButton!` outside of the function and then inside you go `leftButton = UIButton()` etc.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the functions cant seem to work, nothing happens when the buttons are touched: 


/* First Buttons*/
func buttonPressedRightFirst(sender: UIButton!){
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -15, dy: 0))
    buttonPressed = 1




}

func buttonPressedLeftFirst(sender: UIButton!){

    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 15, dy: 0))
    buttonPressed = 0
    self.removeFromParent()
}

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about SpriteKit, so my answer could be wrong. Was your code working before? I suppose you could also try doing `sender.hidden = true` inside your `buttonPressed` functions in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody will be looking for similar answer as me so I'm posting simple solution - to remove clicked button you should call function:

```
sender.removeFromSuperview()
```

This line should be placed in button action target:

```
@objc
func buttonPressedLeftFirst(_ sender: UIButton){

    //...
    sender.removeFromSuperview()
}
```